# Send Reminder filing

Tags: scheduled-reminders

When initiating the Send Reminder job I am getting this error:

[image]

I have similar issues showing up in System Status

[image]

How can I find out what is causing the violation?

Comment: via cv got this

"error_code": -3,
    "debug_info": "INSERT INTO `civicrm_activity_contact` (`activity_id` , `contact_id` , `record_type_id` ) VALUES ( 202280 ,  2067 ,  2 )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hetclub_prod`.`civicrm_activity_contact`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_activity_contact_activity_id` FOREIGN KEY (`activity_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_activity_fudge` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]",
    "entity": "Job",
    "action": "send_reminder",
    "is_error": 1,
    "error_message": "DB Error: constraint violation"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below query

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_activity_contact DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_civicrm_activity_contact_activity_id;

ALTER TABLE civicrm_activity_contact 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_activity_contact_activity_id` FOREIGN KEY (`activity_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_activity` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Note: Take db backup before running query

Comment: Pradeep , you are a saviour sir. That has sorted my issue , thank you very much indeed for this

Answer (score 2):

This ***civicrm_activity_fudge*** foreign key reference doesn't seem to be a part of the default  *civicrm_activity_contact* table structure, you may want to check why it is there and, depending on your circumstances, fix it or remove it from the table. Please do not forget to **backup the whole database** before making changes.